# Migrate Visual Studio Team Services project to new Visual Studio Team Services account with History

Tags: azure-devops

I'm using Visual Studio Team Services xxx.visualstudio.com. Now I have to move entire solution with history to yyy.visualstudio.com. Please let me know how to proceed.
I'm using Visual-studio 2012.

Comment: I found this https://www.visualstudio.com/news/2013-jan-9-vso. But not sure about History logs.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to move the data to a new about that already has data then you need to do a migration. Look at the TFS Integration Tooling.

I recomend that you drop history if you are using TFVC. Git can be migrated easily by simply adding another origin.